# How can I map source to a nested object using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I'm calling an API to get information about a hockey game. The response from the API deserializes to the following:

```cs
public class GameResponseModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public TeamResponseModel HomeTeam { get; set; }
  public TeamResponseModel AwayTeam { get; set; }
  public List<PlayerResponseModel> HomeTeamRoster { get; set; } // <------ FROM
  public List<PlayerResponseModel> AwayTeamRoster { get; set; }
}
```

However, I would prefer to represent the respective roster as a property of the team, like so:

```cs
public class Game {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
  public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public List<Player> Roster { get; set; } // <------ TO
}
```

How can I map `GameResponseModel.HomeTeamRoster` to `Game.HomeTeam.Roster`? E.g.

```cs
CreateMap<PlayerResponseModel, Player>();
CreateMap<TeamResponseModel, Team>();
CreateMap<GameResponseModel, Game>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.HomeTeam.Roster, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HomeTeamRoster))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.AwayTeam.Roster, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AwayTeamRoster));
```

This is a .NET 7 project with AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (12.0.0).

Comment: hI @Santi, If your issue now is not missing the PlayerEntity->Player mapper, could you pls share more code and explain your requirement?

Comment: @Rena I want to map a property from a parent (source) object to a child object of the destination. `GameEntity.HomeTeamRoster` -> `Game.HomeTeam.Roster`. I've updated the question to hopefully clarify a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using [`.AfterMap()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html):

```
CreateMap<GameResponseModel, Game>()
  .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
    dest.HomeTeam.Roster = src.HomeTeamRoster;
    dest.AwayTeam.Roster = src.AwayTeamRoster;
  });
```